# My Del operator in GLSL appears to have an underflow error which results in a black area, how can I prevent that from happening?

Tags: math, glsl, shader, calculus, physics-engine

I am writing a ShaderToy to model De Broglie-Bohm theory to help me visualize quantum mechanics from a deterministic perspective. A key part is the Del(∇) operator for calculating gradients for diffusing a field.

Right now I appear to have something that looks like it's diffusing, but I believe it runs into an underflow error and a black splotch appears. How do I prevent it from forming? This is what it looks like:

[image: blob with black center]

Here is the Del operator code:

```
vec4 del(in vec4[9] points){
    vec4 deltaX = ((points[2 * 3 + 0] + points[2 * 3 + 1] + points[2 * 3 + 2])/3.
     - (points[0 * 3 + 0] + points[0 * 3 + 1] + points[0 * 3 + 2])/3.)/2.;
    vec4 deltaY = ((points[0 * 3 + 2] + points[1 * 3 + 2] + points[2 * 3 + 2])/3.
     - (points[0 * 3 + 0] + points[1 * 3 + 0] + points[2 * 3 + 0])/3.)/2.;
    return vec4((deltaX + deltaY).rgb, 1.);
}


vec4 delTex(sampler2D tex, ivec2 coord){
    vec4[9] surroundingPoints = vec4[9](vec4(1),vec4(1),vec4(1),vec4(1),vec4(1),vec4(1),vec4(1),vec4(1),vec4(1));
    
    for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < 3; y++){
            surroundingPoints[x * 3 + y] = texelFetch(tex,(ivec2(coord) + (ivec2(x,y) - ivec2(1))), 0);
        }
    }
    return del(surroundingPoints);
}

void mainImage(out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 coord) {
    if(iMouse.x > 0. && iMouse.y > 0. && abs(coord.x - iMouse.x) < 5. && abs(coord.y - iMouse.y) < 5.) {
        fragColor = vec4(1.,0.,1.,1.); return;
    }
    if(coord.x == 0. || coord.y == 0.){
        fragColor = vec4(1.,0.,1.,1.);return;
    }

        // texelFetch(iChannel0, ivec2(coord), 0) + 
        fragColor = texelFetch(iChannel0, ivec2(coord), 0) + delTex(iChannel0, ivec2(coord)); return;

    //fragColor = texelFetch(iChannel0, ivec2(coord), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out, the numbers were overflowing because the gradient was being added to the original pixel. I used the min() function to clamp the number to below 1. and there is no black square anymore.